# Connect my NodeJS app to mongo in docker-compose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have reviewed these related questions and their answers but I have been faced with a new problem in which I'm not able to change the default port of mongo.

My docker file:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine3.14
RUN addgroup app
RUN adduser app -G app -S
USER app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
ENV MONGODB_CONNECTION_STRING=mongodb://mongo:27017/stock-trade
ENV PORT=3000
ENV HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV LOG_LEVEL=debug
ENV LOG_NAMESPACES=app:*
ENV APP_NAME="Stock Trade"
ENV NO_LOGS=false
ENV TZ=UTC-4
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node","./build/index.js"]
```

my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:

       stock-trade:
           container_name: stock-trade
           image: stock-trade
           restart: always
           build: .
           expose: 
             - 3000
           ports:
             - "3000:3000"
           links:
             - mongo
       mongo:
             container_name: mongo
             image: mongo
             volumes:
               - ./data:/data/db
             expose: 
               - 27017
             ports:
               - '27017:27017'
             command: mongod --bind_ip 0.0.0.0
```

so they are working fine but I'm not able to change the mongo port to the new one.

My docker file:

```
...
ENV MONGODB_CONNECTION_STRING=mongodb://mongo:27018/stock-trade
...
```

my docker-compose file:

```
...
             expose: 
               - 27018
             ports:
               - '27018:27017'
...
```

I appreciated any suggestion to address this problem.

Comment: You don't change that `MONGODB_CONNECTION_STRING` at all.  Connections between containers always use the "normal" port; they ignore any `ports:` remapping.  `expose:` does absolutely nothing and you can safely delete it.

Comment: @DavidMaze but I saw in videos and sample pages that they are able to change the default port especially for MongoDB but I don't know why I'm not able to do that!

Comment: Inside Docker, as an implementation detail, each container has its own IP address and port space.  Is there a reason you want to change the port number inside Docker?  The `ports:` affect how you'd connect to the container from outside Docker (if at all) and it's okay for that to be different.